# Cross Domain WebSocket Connection [Spring Boot]

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, cross-domain, spring-websocket

I have two instances of spring boot services running. let's say 'app1:8080' and another instance 'app2:7070'. Where as 'app1:8080' is hosting a html page , which tries to connect a web-socket connection with 'app2:7070', whenever it get launched. 
Something like this :
var webSocket = new WebSocket("ws://app2:7070/socket-endpoint");

But i am always getting 403 error message.  I have read about the cross-domain and have tried to register the 'app1:8080' in 'app2:7070'.
But couldn't find any solution.

Server technology : spring boot
client technology : HTML5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this results from cross origin calls. You have different options to solve this:

- put a load balancer like nginx in front of both applications and serve them with the same base URL
- serve the html from the same application (the easiest solution if its a small application)
- or allow cross origin calls in app2 from app1 in your case, like documented [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

Comment: can't serve both the applications with the same url as both are an independent application neither can serve from the same application{as explained in the question}.
can you please try to share an example for cross origin calls and will it work for an "wss" calls as well ?

Comment: this CORS config [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework) should also be picked up by the websocket

Comment: thanks, able to achieve that. But not sure about the 'wss' still.

Comment: sorry for the late update, but worked on the wss and worked like a charm. Thanks jonathan.